# Java startup arguments

Tags: java

I searched dozens of threads about this topic.

What I am looking for is to start a program using custom attributes, like:

```
java -C:/randof/...FROMPATH -C:/rudolf/...TOPATH
```

I want to start the program using the commandline (obviously) and directly passing arguments in it. The from and topath that are passed should be able to be used internally.

I cannot properly extract them though. If I iterate over "args", it brings me an error "Unrecognized option:". How is the thing I wanna achieve possible?

And is it only possible by passing "VM-Arguments"? This would mean that the arguments would be available over all java programs that run at the same time if not mistaken. I would like to enclose the scope if possible.

Comment: please post your source code

Answer (score 0):

use -- before the arguments of your program:

```
java -C... -other-java-options -- -your-app-options etc
```

in the above command line java is the executable and all the rest are arguments that are passed by your shell to java. Java tries to interpret them. The common way to tell a program, that the arguments to it are ending here, and from here the arguments are meant for something else (in this case to your java code) so don't bother parsing them, just pass them on.

Comment: Sry for responding so late, I'll try it as soon as I'm on it again, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The primary way to get command line options to be recognized as options to the program you are writing and not as options to the java executable is to use defines `-Dproperty=value` and then you can pull these out using the `System` object.  If you don't insist on having a leading dash, then the options will become elements in the `String[]` parameter passed to `main`.

Other `-XXXX` arguments are passed to the java executable (actually the -D is passed to the java executable too, but the java executable then makes it available to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use "-" when you give the arguments.
Just write (if the compiled file has the name SofExample.class):
java SofExample C:/fromPath C:/toPath
and then in the program you will be able to use the arguments, because they will be in the args String array.

For example:
public class SofExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String fromPath=args[0];
    final String toPath=args[1];

    //Args checks and other codes come here to use fromPath and toPath...
}
```

### }

These arguments can be used only in this program code, not in all programs running in the JVM.

I hope I could help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers did what I wanted (maybe my question was badly formulated), but I found the solution.

You can just add the parameters you need without a specific operator.

Consider the following main method:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    for (String a : args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Here is the output for the following inputs:

`java -jar YOURJARFILENAME.jar C:/Users/RUDOLF`

```
//Output:
C:/Users/RUDOLF
```

`java -jar YOURJARFILENAME.jar C:/abc C:/def`

```
//Output:
C:/abc
C:/def
```

If you need to hand over filepaths that contain whitespaces, just add `""` around every path. This will ensure that it is read as one argument and not be splitted up.

Problem: `java -jar YOURJARFILENAME.jar C:/users/arnold schwarzenegger/desktop`

```
//Output:
C:/users/arnold
chwarzenegger/desktop
```

Solution: `java -jar YOURJARFILENAME.jar "C:/users/arnold schwarzenegger/desktop"`

```
//Output:
C:/users/arnold schwarzenegger/desktop
```